# JS export function case a or case b

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, velo

I am working on a pop-up menu that should pop up when the user hovers over a button.
I am not completely new to coding, however I am pretty rusty.

I have written the following code so far - but it doesn't really work:

```
export function button45_mouseIn(event) {
  $w("#box8").show();
}

export function button45_mouseOut(event) {
  $w("#box8").hide();
}

export function box8_mouseIn(event) {
  $w("#box8").show();
}

export function box8_mouseOut(event) {
  $w("#box8").hide();
}
```

*button45 = The button over which the user hovers |
box8 = The box with the pop-up menu*

My idea was a code like "export function button45_mouseIn(event) ***OR / AND*** box8_mouseIn(event) → $w('#box8').show()"
Can someone write me a full short code directly there or has a better idea / a better full short code?

I am really happy and thank you in advance about/for any answer!

Comment: You should just export all the functions. Then the application that imports can decide which functions to call as it needs them.

Comment: Thanks for the reply  Can you may show me how? Like I said, I'm a bit rusty at the moment regarding coding...

Comment: Can you let us know what is currently happening and how it differs from what you want so we can try to diagnose the problem? Have you made sure to wire these functions using the Properties & Events panel?

Comment: Hey Sam  Thanks for the reply! The box shows up when hovering above the button, and as long as you stay over the box. Unfortunately, the box doesn't hide when leaving the box with the mouse – it only hides if you move the mouse over the button and then away... You can try urself → [www.dronec.de](https://www.dronec.de) hover over the button "Shooting" in the upper left.